# How to programmatically open a chrome extension popup window from background.html

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Thanks in advance!

What I want to achieve is to open the popup window when a special tag is detected on a webpage by my extension. After searching for a while it seems like the popup can only be opened when user clicks the extension. Is it true?

Or could I get the location of my extension's icon on browser? Maybe I could draw a window and display under the extension icon to make it looks just like the popup window.

Comment: [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063002/preventing-a-chrome-extensions-popup-html-from-opening-itself) wants the opposite effect and can't get his popup window not to open. Take a look at his code to open your popup page ;)

Comment: Just for the record: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399859

Comment: One approach that might work would be to setup a keyboard shortcut for the pop up in the extension's manifest, then use an executable file to artificially trigger that keyboard shortcut. See [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) for more info about how to communicate with an executable file from an extension.

Answer (score 16):

It is impossible to get the extension window to open without a user clicking on it... However, you can get the extension popup page to open in a new tab as follows:

**1) Set your [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) in your manifest file...**

```
"background_page": "background.html",
```

This is where you will run the code to see whether the special tag is detected... background pages can constantly run code in the background, and it is up to you to set a repeat loop to check whether you variable condition is true every so often...

**2) Enable [tabs permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) in your manifest file...**

```
"permissions": [ "tabs" ],
```

This permission is needed for step 3 (Allows the background page to open a new tab)

**3) In background page, call [`create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) and point to the extension popup url.**

```
if(condition == true){
  chrome.tabs.create({url:"popup.html"});
}
```

Comment: "background_page" isn't recognised anymore as a manifest key

Answer (score 11):

You cannot fake click on browser action, but you can still open the popup page from the background script as usual window popup and it will work as expected. So for example the html page of your browser action is "popup.html"

```
window.open("popup.html", "extension_popup", "width=300,height=400,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
```

Note: you can call it only from the background script (event page). Therefore you need to register the background script in your manifest file and add an event handler, which would open the popup.You can read more about event pages here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

Comment: Note: If window.open is not called as a result of a user action, such as a click, then it will be blocked as popup by most browsers

Comment: @JanacMeena That doesn't apply to Chrome extensions calling window.open

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. So simple, but working! Thank you @devza !

Comment: this may help, window.open("chrome-extension://YOUR_CHROME_EXTENSION_ID/_generated_background_page.html")

Comment: Can I open one of the modal popup from popup.html instead of whole extension HTML using window.open()?

Comment: In manifest V3: window is giving undefined in background.js

Comment: In Manifest V3, the following does the job but you lose the functionality of disabling scrollbars and resize: `chrome.windows.create({ url: "popup.html", height: 400, width: 400, type: 'popup' });`

Answer (score 7):

If by popup you mean browser action popup then you are right, there is no way of opening it programmatically.

You can embed whatever you need from your popup on demand directly into a page through a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html). I think this would be the best solution.

If your popup doesn't contain anything fancy, maybe [desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/notifications.html) would be enough for you.

Creating a new window and positioning it under the url bar would be pretty awkward solution and not very user friendly.

Comment: Why does Firefox have openPopup but not chrome?

Answer (score 3):

For manifest v3 I do something like this. Again, you cannot do this directly, instead you need to open a popup window like the posts above suggest.

```
//contentscript.js

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({
    left: window.screenLeft + window.outerWidth,
    top: window.screenTop
}), (response) => {});
```

```
//backgroundscript.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(request);
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
            type: "popup",
            top: data.top,
            left: data.left-400,
            width: 400,
            height: 600,
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: When I use this method, it gives an Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://xxxxxx/popup.html". The extension manifest must request permission to access this host... any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

For completeness: There is also [`chrome.action.openPopup()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-openPopup), but it is marked as `Dev channel` and has been for a year now. I have tried `google-chrome-unstable` (the dev channel) and it does work. But it doesn't look super likely that it will be released anytime soon, see discussion in [chromium #1245093 - New Extension API: action.openPopup()](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1245093#c22)

Comment: It looks like it is available now however it "Requires policy" whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add to [devza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250690/12473000) above. His answer is great if the popup doesnt need to communicate back with the page - otherwise you have a problem because your content scripts aren't interacting with the original window. This answer relies on the page being aware of the extension (sending and receiving messages) - meaning you have to be in control of the page as well. What I did is cumbersome but it works:

1. Listen for postMessage from page to background script, and open the new window as devza suggested.
2. Encode the original page's url as the new window's name (the url is available on the message's event object).
3. When you need to propogate from the popup back to the original page, call window.opener.postMessage from the popup - this message is triggered on the background page's window.
   The message should include the data and the encoded origin(=window.name).
4. Listen for a message in the background script. When you receive the message, you can use the Chrome.tabs api (enable "tabs" permission in manifest.json) to find the relevant tab - usually this would be the first tab in the list, but now it isn't, because of the way the popup was opened. Here's where the encoded origin is useful - iterate through the tabs array and find the tab where tab.url===origin.
5. This is the relevant tab to send a message to (=to the relevant content script).
6. The content script should listen for said message, which should at the very least include the data.
7. The content script can then raise an event/use the relevant data to update the dom.