# Preventing a Chrome extension's popup.html from opening itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that has a `background.html` file which requests information from an API once every minute. Once it receives the information, it messages `popup.html` with the JSON information with which popup uses to append new HTML elements onto the popup's body.

The problem is background is constantly running (as it should), but it will ping popup even when popup is closed. This causes popup to open itself every minute which is very annoying.

I want to know, is there a way to see if popup is closed and not do anything if that's the case? Or is there another way to prevent popup opening on its own?

Here's the [Github repository](https://github.com/theabraham/Question-Stack), but the important parts are highlighted below.

Here's how I'm pinging popup:

```
// background.js

function sendQuestions()                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    var questions = JSON.parse(db.getItem(storage));                                                                                                                                                        
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(appid, { 'questions': questions }, function() {});                                                                                                                         
}  

setInterval(sendQuestions, 60e3);
```

Here's how popup handles it:

```
// popup.js

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {                                                                                                                                                  
    if (request.questions) {                                                                                                                                                                                
        displayQuestions(request.questions);                                                                                                                                                                
    }
});

function displayQuestions(questions)                                                                                                                                                                        
{     
    for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                
        var question = questions[i];  
        var htmlBlock = // ... generate a block of html ...
        $('#container').prepend(htmlBlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are pinging popup? If it causes popup to open it would be awesome as AFAIK it wasn't possible to open it programmatically before :)

Comment: I added a variable `isPopup = true` to popup.html and then used `getViews` from background.html, and then check for each view whether it has the `isPopup` property. In that case the popup is opened, otherwise not. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews

Comment: @pimvbd The communication is only between `popup.html` and `background.html`, so I know whose who. Is there a way to tell that the popup is currently closed from background, though? In that case, I could use that boolean to prevent background from even sending a message.

Comment: @Gisborne: Well, `getViews` only returns currently open windows, i.e. always bg and sometimes popup. Just check whether any of the returned windows contain the `isPopup` property and you know whether the popup is open or not.

Comment: Oh, I see! I'll try that in a moment.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describing. Popup is not opening by itself for me (and it shouldn't). Which OS and Chrome version do you use? This seems like a Chrome bug to be.

Comment: Mac OSX 10.6 with Chrome 12.0.742.53 beta. I apparently have some updates to install too, so I'll do that once I'm outside class.

Comment: I'm trying the popup thing like so: `var views = chrome.extension.getViews({ 'type': 'popup' });`. When I do `console.log(views.length)` I consistently get `1` as the response even when I put it on loop and open a popup (I also updated.)

Answer (score 0):

Open a long [lived connection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/#connect) from the popup to the background_page anytime it opens. In the background_page you can check to see if the connection is currently active. If it is pass the necessary messages otherwise wait until the connection is active.