# how to open default_popup on contextmenu item click in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

how to open default_popup on contextmenu item click in chrome extension

is there anyway? when user click on context menu item than we can call/open html file which define in default_popup for browser action.

I have already go through on the following links. there answer was no (any possible way). if no what do I do to achieve this any alternative?

[how-to-open-the-default-popup-from-context-menu-in-a-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851700/how-to-open-the-default-popup-from-context-menu-in-a-chrome-extension)

[how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The Google Chrome developer team has stated that this feature will not be added in a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30491):

> The philosophy for browser and page action popups is that they must be triggered by 
>   user action.

An alternative would be to open the Popup.html file in a new tab using the following code or something similar

> Note: Needs to be called from background page and requires the "tabs"
>   permission

```
// Opens Popup.html in new tab
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
  // Tab opened.
});
```