# How to programmatically open chrome extension popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a created a desktop notification using google extension which works great:

```
icon = '';
    var popup = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(my notification');
            icon, 'Awesome title', 'Click here to view more. ');
    popup.show();
```

Is there a way to launch the actual google extension popup.html (as shown on the image below), when the user click on the the desktop notification?

[image: The popup.html]
[image: The desktop notification]

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open my extension's pop-up with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript)

Comment: One approach that might work would be to setup a keyboard shortcut for the pop up in the extension's manifest, then use an executable file to artificially trigger that keyboard shortcut. See [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) for more info about how to communicate with an executable file from an extension.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't, but if you want to open the popup in a new tab instead, this is how you would do it:

Put this before you call `show`

```
popup.onclick = function() { 
    chrome.tabs.create({url : "popup.html"}); 
    popup.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually the idea is not to open the popup.html in another tab but to launch the exetension as shown on the first image.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript. The google dev explicitly said that they would not allow this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add to the comment that Miscreant posted.

> One approach that might work would be to setup a keyboard shortcut for
>   the pop up in the extension's manifest, then use an executable file to
>   artificially trigger that keyboard shortcut. See Native Messaging for
>   more info about how to communicate with an executable file from an
>   extension

This is how you set up a shortcut key that opens your extension.

```
...
"commands": {
"_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
        }
}
```

[Here's the API on 'commands'](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands).

Comment: I never played with Native Messaging, but I found some documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that! You're a hero :)

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work? Are there any issues you've come across/ is it consistent across browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe we can only get option page address from chrome extension's manifest json file, then open the address like `chrome-extension://<extensionId>/options.html`, which extension can not do, but require external program to get option addresses.