# is it possible to launch an extension from a website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Had a qq: is it possible to launch an extension (that is already installed) when someone clicks on a link ?

For example, let's say on my website I have a button that says "click here to launch the extension". After they install my chrome extension, when a user clicks on this button, could the extension launch? (e.g.- the popup to open).

The goal is this: I have an extension that acts like a search bar. I also have search on the website, but I wanted it to search using the extension instead of the website if a user chooses to.

Thanks for any info,
Y

Comment: Would a custom "protocol handler" (actually a URI scheme handler, but nobody calls them that) work for you, per this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7087728/157957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for a way to programmatically open the extension's popup, then you will be disappointed (as **[it cannot be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928979/how-to-programmatically-open-chrome-extension-popup-html)**).

If it serves your purpose, you could do something like this:

1. Have your extension inject a content script into your webpage.
2. Have the content script bind to a button's `click` event.
3. When the button is clicked: Pass some parameters to the extension's background page, let the extension perform the search and send the results back to the webpage.