# From my website, programmatically initiate the installation of a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I achieve this functionality in my web application?

[image: go to this location for better understanding]

Here is the image showing the extension adding pop up:

[image: and here is the image showing the extension adding pop up.]

Everywhere in Stack Overflow and Google it is telling that we cannot add extension pop up like:

[How to programmatically open chrome extension popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928979/how-to-programmatically-open-chrome-extension-popup-html)

How can we display this alert "add extension"?

Comment: The question [How to programmatically open chrome extension popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17928979) is not talking about the same type of popup. It is talking about the type of popup which is defined within your extension. You appear to be talking about programmatically installing an extension from your website, which causes Chrome to confirm with the user that the installation is desired.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is known [Inline Plugin Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

#### Pre-requisite:

Before adding inline installation you must:

1. [Publish](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish) your plugin on Chrome Webstore.
2. Must have your domain verified on [Google Webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) - [Verified Site Requirement](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#verified-site)

#### Installation:

Then, to prompt the user to install the plugin while they are still on your site (not redirecting to Chrome Webstore) follow these steps:

1. Add a `<Link />` to your Webstore Plugin, e.g.

   ```
   <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
   ```

   more details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#cws-link).
2. Trigger the installation (say after the user clicks a button),

   ```
   $('#install').on('click', function(){
         if(window.chrome){
            chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)
       }
   })
   ```

Make sure to checkout [Official Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) for more.