# Show chrome extension popup implicitly when user visits a website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm developing a chrome extension that lists offers while visiting some shopping websites. For example, when a user visits flipkart.com, extension popup would show up automatically without having to click on the extension icon. I've managed to do all other aspects of the extension except **automatically** opening the popup while user visits a website.

Things that I've tried and failed so far are listed below,

- Looked for chrome action API method to manually trigger the click event
- Use chrome.commands that works based on keyboard shortcuts

I have read some answers for questions nearly matching. Unfortunately, some accepted answers say that this requirement is not allowed due to security reasons. But, I've seen it's working in a chrome extension namely **Honey**. That made me feel like there must be some work around to achieve the same.

Manifest file is copied below;

```
{
"name": "SaveMore",
"description": "Know the best offers available",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
"action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "/images/logo16.png",
    "32": "/images/logo32.png",
    "48": "/images/logo48.png",
    "128": "/images/logo128.png"
  }
},
"icons": {
  "16": "/images/logo16.png",
  "32": "/images/logo32.png",
  "48": "/images/logo48.png",
  "128": "/images/logo128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["app.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
"content_security_policy": {},
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Any help would become a life saver

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically open chrome extension popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928979/how-to-programmatically-open-chrome-extension-popup-html)

Comment: also read [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/zero-to-hero-chrome-extensions-4060520daf59)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen This way the popup opens up in a new tab or window unlike normal user clicking the pinned icon behaviour. I'll read the shared resource. Thanks

Comment: Currently the only way is to add the UI as a DOM element into the web page. In the future there'll be chrome.action.openPopup.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: Did you find a way do to it?