# Chrome Extension launch from website button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do have an extension (developed by me). It works fine. However I can't get the idea on how to launch extension from regular button on a web-page.

The main action (opens Chrome Popup) is performed when I click on extension icon.

But I also need to be able to launch extension via button click on website.
Should I send a msg to extension from website via javascript or?

Or I can go in a different way, and insert content from extension popup to website placeholder. A bit awkward working with extensions.

Any advice appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you open your extension's elements inside the site in a modal, isn't an easy solution?
Because there is no API to open the popup programmatically.

Comment: Programmatically opening the popup may not currently be possible but you can still communicate with you website form a content script and do any required operations that you would in the popup.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. But from the looks of it, it may be available soon.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796396/3383751) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript).