# Open Chrome Extension From External Web Page Button Without Clicking The Browser Extension Button

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My web page has a login section. I want the extension to open when the user clicks on the login button. Is it possible? I want to open the extension after logging in directly on my web page without clicking the extension button in the browser.

Comment: It's possible and there should be many examples of doing that even on StackOverflow. The only restriction is that the extension has to show its UI inside the page or as a separate window.

Comment: Is there an example you can offer in this matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open my extension's pop-up with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript)