# Show extension browser_action from background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I'm trying to do is to automatically trigger the extension's browser_action from backend.js script of the extension. The extension page should open automatically when user open particular website.

[image: Sample extension browser_action content]

I know I can provide the shortcut for opening this and/or modify extension's icon to show the user that something happened on the extension.

But in my case, I'd actually prefer to open this menu like it was clicked manually. Can I somehow emit a specific event to do so? Or can I do it somehow?

It couldn't be done 3 years ago, but maybe chrome API changed since that time?

Comment: Extensions can't do that (well there is an experimental hidden method in dev and canary though). You can show a notification using chrome.notifications API or HTML5 Notifications API or create a new window using chrome.windows.create.

Comment: Well, I would like to show a little bit more than simple notification. Something like an interactive panel.

Comment: FWIW, notifications can have buttons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript

Comment: Yup, because browsers API doesn't change dynamically 3 years from the mentioned question. Thank you @JoshLee