# Undesired Default Popup Below Extension Icon

Tags: javascript, html, json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

**Problem: I'm currently facing a problem. which is that when I click the extension icon, a small popup appears below it in addition to the new window that opens. This small popup is unwanted and not part of my intended functionality.**

The image shows a Chrome extension icon with a small popup below it. This undesired popup is not part of the intended behaviour and is causing issues.

[image]

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "TimeTracker Pomodoro",
    "description": "Boost productivity with a Pomodoro timer and task manager in one Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon-16.png",
      "32": "images/icon-32.png",
      "64": "images/icon-64.png",
      "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup":"popup/popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "32": "images/icon-32.png",
        "64": "images/icon-64.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
      }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["script/content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html"
    }
        }
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Check if a window from your extension is already open
    chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true, windowTypes: ["popup"] }, function (windows) {
      const extensionWindows = windows.filter((win) => {
        return win.tabs.some((tab) => {
          return tab.url.endsWith("popup.html");
        });
      });
        
      if (extensionWindows.length > 0) {
        // A window from your extension is already open, bring it to focus
        chrome.windows.update(extensionWindows[0].id, { focused: true });
      } else {
        // Open a new Chrome window when the extension icon is clicked
        chrome.windows.create({
          url: "popup/popup.html",
          type: "popup",
          width: 800,
          height: 400,
          left: Math.round(screen.availWidth / 2 - 300),
          top: Math.round(screen.availHeight / 2 - 200),
        });
      }
    });
        });
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    welcome to Productivity 
    <div id="popup-container">
      <!-- Your Pomodoro timer, to-do list, and other UI elements go here -->
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: background.js , options.html and content.js are  empty.

I clicked on the Chrome extension icon, hoping to open a new window. However, along with the new window, a small popup appeared below the extension icon. This popup was not part of what I wanted to happen, and it's causing an issue because it's not the expected behavior.

Comment: The default popup it because you have `"default_popup":"popup/popup.html"` in your manifest.json. see this answer for more details on what needs to change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745123/how-to-run-popup-html-without-using-default-popup-chrome-extension