# How to keep open extension pop up after clicking outside pf extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created one chrome extension for translation but i am facing one issue. whenever i click outside the extension it is closed. How can I keep thi dialogue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show it inside the page, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508273)