# Chrome Extension: Messaging content script from an opened window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension, and in my case, I need "popup.html" to sometimes appear and sometimes disappear, without having the user to click on the extension's icon. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250690/8165952) answer, which explains that you can open the popup page using *"window.open"* instead.

That seemed like a good solution for me, especially because I don't want to open "popup.html" in a new tab. It has to be **on** the current tab, and I shall simply play with its visibility.

The problem is: After opening *"popup.html"* as a new window, by using the following command inside *"background.js"*:

```
window.open("popup.html", "extension_popup", "width=300,height=400,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
```

Which indeed makes *"popup.html"* to appear as expected, I simply cannot use it to send messages to the content script. What do I mean? inside *"popup.html"* I have some logic, and when a button is clicked, a function is invoked in *"background.js"*. Then *"background.js"* sends a message to the content script this way:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "doSomething"});
  })
```

Problem is, nothing happens and the message is **not** sent. 
On the other hand, when "popup.html" is opened in a regular way by pressing on the extension's icon, the message **does** passes on to the content script and the logic works as expected. It does **not** work only when "popup.html" is opened by "window.open".

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible at all? My guess is that "background.js" does not really function as a background page for the extension when I open popup.html by using "window.open(..)".

Help is much appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: Firstly, is the `tabs[0].id` actually equal to the tab id your popup is? Secondly, I have a weird feeling that opening a window from `background.js` 1) is not healthy 2) is not creating a page that would run in conditions like it was open by a normal tab. It could be that the page that is spawned by a `background.js` could run in the context of `background.js`; this would mean it would not listen to the events for the normal pages but would listen to `runtime` events. This however is a very blind assumption.

Comment: `currentWindow: true` will refer to the popup window, of course. You can try `lastFocusedWindow: true` instead or enumerate all browser windows using `chrome.windows` API. See the documentation. P.S. in case the popup is  shown on user gesture you can use chrome.browserAction.openPopup.

Comment: @wOxxOm according to: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction, there is no chrome.browserAction.openPopup - only chrome.browserAction.setPopup, which doesn't help me unfortunately. lastFocusedWindow: true didn't help as well, but thanks anyway!

Comment: The documentation is outdated.