# Is it possible to animate extension popup opening?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I developed a simple chrome extension. Following the answers in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544256/how-to-programmatically-open-a-chrome-extension-popup-window-from-background-htm) I was able to programmatically open the popup window on certain webpages. The default behavior of the popup is to open a window at the top right. Is it possible to modify this behavior? Ideally, I would like the popup window to slide in from the right after the automatic `window.open` is invoked in the background script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no control over how and where it appears.

If you want something like slide-in, you're better off injecting your GUI elements into the page itself.

How feasible it is depends on whether you need to inject it into an arbitrary page or if you're working with just one specific website. Shadow DOM might help you isolate styles from the parent page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was under the impression that it could not be done but needed a second opinion on that. I think injecting a script will be counterproductive since, the extension works on multiple sites and the content script will need more than trivial adjustments to look right on each site. Anyways, thanks for the definitive answer.