# Open chrome extension via anchor tag or window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome-extension, which requires the users to log in. When the user successfully logs in, the server would redirect them to a specified URL. The mobile implementation of the same opens the mobile app, and I am trying to look for something that does the same.

The solution that I am after is kind of how an anchor tag or `window.open` works in opening an app on your mobile or even making a call. Just like that, I want to open the Chrome extension programmatically.

I did try the below URL, but it takes me to a new tab with blocked message

```
window.open('chrome-extension://<extension unique ID>/index.html')
```

Comment: I used reference from [this blog here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium)

Comment: index.html should be listed in `web_accessible_resources`, see examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm can u send me link to the examples please?

Comment: @wOxxOm okay adding index.html to `web_accessible_resources`worked, but its opening in a tab and not opening the actual extension.

Comment: See [How to programmatically open a chrome extension popup window from background.html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250690)